# Sketching the curve $\frac{y^2}{a^2}+1=\frac{a}{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, curves

Firstly, if don't understand the domain of the function as the constant $a$ is not specified to be positive or negative, (correct me if the sign doesn't make a difference).
 I tried finding the symmetry of the curve and it comes out to be symmetric about x-axis. (Since $(x,y)$ satifies the equation iff $(x,-y)$ does.
 Also the derivative turns out to be negative (if we assume only the positive root). **(Should we not consider the negative sign of the root)**. i.e. $y^2=a$, then $y=\pm\sqrt a$.
 Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be easier to flip the question around and plot $x$ as a function to $y$.

$$\begin{align}
\frac {y^2}{a^2}+1&=\frac ax\\
\frac xa&=\frac{a^2}{y^2+a^2}\\
x&=\frac{a^3}{y^2+a^2}\end{align}$$

Assume $x$ and $y$ are the vertical and horizontal axes respectively.

First plot $x=y^2+a^2$, an upward opening parabola with $x$-intercept of $a^2$.

Take the reciprocal and multiply by $a^3$ to plot $x=\frac{a^3}{y^2+a^2}$. The $x$-intercept is $a$, and the asymptotes are $x=0$ as $y\to \pm\infty$.

Flip the axes around to give the required graph.

Comment: By 'flipping the axes' do you mean rotating about the line $x=y$?

Comment: I would prefer to express as $x/a = \frac{1}{(y/a)^2+1}$. First graph $x=\frac{1}{y^2+1}$, then stretch it vertically and horizontally by a factor of $a$

Comment: @JohnJoy - yes, that would be very nice.

Comment: @SwapnilTripathi - yes... to be exact, a reflection (not rotation) on the line $x=y$.